# How to convert the Time from "1hr 26min" format to just hour

Tags: flutter, dart

for example, I'm getting "1hr 26min" as Time I need to format it to an hour or just hours and minutes separately. how do I do that?

```
DateFormat.Hm().format(DateTime.parse(FetchList[index].Duration))
                                    .toString()
```

**This was my unsuccessful approach.**

Comment: give example of ur output that u need.

Comment: I just want to extract the hour and minutes separately. If it's "1hr 26min" then 1 for an hour and 26 for minutes seprately.

Comment: Does it maintain the format for different time?

Comment: Is the format you are getting from the API always the same? Then you could extract the numbers with something like this: `const hours = apiResponse.split('hr')[0]; const minutes = apiResponse.split(' ')[1].split('min')[0]; `

Comment: @GRaw can you please let me know which format you want? Which is your expected output

Comment: i need it in string.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
void datetimeConvert() {
String hr = '1hr 16min';
var splitValue = hr.split(' ');
print("Split Value ${splitValue}");
final Map<int, String> values = {for (int i = 0; i < 
splitValue.length; i++) i: splitValue[i]};
 print(values);
 final value1 = values[0];
 final value2 = values[1];
 var aStr = value1?.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[^0-9]'), ''); // '23'
 print("first ${aStr}");
 var aStr2 = value2?.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[^0-9]'), ''); // '23'
 print("second ${aStr2}");
 }
```

Comment: not working, throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string and remove all char,

```dart
  final data = "1hr 26min";

  final separation = data.split(" ").toList();

  int hour =
      int.tryParse(separation.first.replaceAll(RegExp("[a-z]"), "")) ?? 0;
  int min = int.tryParse(separation.last.replaceAll(RegExp("[a-z]"), "")) ?? 0;
  print("h $hour min $min");
```

Comment: i'm getting the duration from api in string "1hr 26min".

Comment: i think in need to convert it to a string that DateTime can accept.

Comment: Can you update the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
const hours = apiResponse.split('hr')[0];
const minutes = apiResponse.split(' ')[1].split('min')[0];
```

by - **Jakob Schweighofer**

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the hour and minute values into a `Duration` object for further manipulation.

The implementation below is more efficient than using `split`, `indexOf` with multiple characters, or a regular expression.

```dart
const durationString = '1hr 26min';
final separatorIndex = durationString.indexOf(' ');
final hours = int.parse(durationString.substring(0, separatorIndex - 2));
final minutes = int.parse(durationString.substring(separatorIndex + 1, durationString.length - 3));
final duration = Duration(hours: hours, minutes: minutes);
```